# Why can't I get my annotations to show on the Map?

Tags: swift, mapkit

What I have is a simple map layout Where it finds the current users location and then it places a pin at that current location. I think I have the code right but I don't see the pin when I run my location.

```
import MapKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var coreLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

var locationManager:LocationManager!

//allowing permission to use your location

@IBOutlet weak var Map: MKMapView!

@IBOutlet weak var myLocation: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    coreLocationManager.delegate = self

    locationManager = LocationManager.sharedInstance

    let authorizationCode = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    if authorizationCode == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined && coreLocationManager.respondsToSelector("requestAlwaysAuthorization") || coreLocationManager.respondsToSelector("requestWhenInUseAuthorization"){

        if NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription") != nil {
        coreLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }else{
            print("No description provided")
        }

    }else{
        getLocation()

    }

}
//getting your location

func getLocation(){

    locationManager.startUpdatingLocationWithCompletionHandler { (latitude, longitude, status, verboseMessage, error) -> () in
        self.displayLocation(CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude))
    }


}

func displayLocation(Location:CLLocation){

    Map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Location.coordinate.latitude, Location.coordinate.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)), animated: true)

    let locationPinCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: Location.coordinate.longitude)
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = locationPinCoord










    //SHOW POINTS
    Map.addAnnotation(annotation)
    Map.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)



}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status  != CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined || status != CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied || status != CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted{

    }
}


@IBAction func updateLocation(sender: AnyObject) {
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all you **must** add the `MKMapViewDelegate` in your `ViewController`. Because you will need to use **MapView Delegate Methods** to show your **annotations**. Look at my codes and add them to your project. It should be work if you get user `currentLocation` coordinates without any problem. If it doesn't work let me know.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class YourViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard let pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("YourReusableIdentifier") as! MKAnnotationView else { return nil }
        pinView.annotation = annotation
        pinView.canShowCallout = true
        return pinView
    }

    // It directs to CalloutView position to Above of Pin Position
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
        // Do something when user didSelect the Annotation View.
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        getLocation() // Starting Location Manager Update this is your method !
    }
}
```